# How to export Derby database to sql insert file using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, intellij-idea, derby

I am trying to extract the current database to a .sql insert file.  I am using IntelliJ and a Derby embedded database.  I know how to do this manual through IntelliJ, but I want to do so through JDBC.  I would like to store the file within the project as well, so it can be ran as a sql script to insert to the db later on.

Comment: You can unload a table to a comma-separated-values (CSV) file, then reload that data from that CSV file. Does that help?

Comment: ahh okay, yes.  I don't actually need it necessarily to be a .sql file, just something that can be loaded into the data again later on for save state implementation.

Comment: Here's the docs for the CSV export function: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/ref/rrefexportproc.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to extract a Derby database to a .sql file that can be ran later on.

Instead, simply zip up your Derby database folder and unzip it later on.

Answer (score 0):

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/admin/hubprnt43.html#Backing+Up+a+Database

There is no option for backup as sql file format. However, to perform an offline backup of a database, simply use operating system commands to copy the database directory. The database must be shut down prior to performing an offline backup.